# Merge tags [docker-for-windows], [docker-on-windows] and [docker-windows]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[docker-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows), [docker-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-on-windows) and [docker-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-windows) all appear to be trying to do the same thing; it seems like [docker-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows) is the most common (93 qns vs. 7  & 72 at time of writing, and it has usage guidance), but I'm not sure what the convention should be for this kind of platform specific tag.

Comment: In my opinion, the convention should be [docker] [windows] (i.e., separate tags).

Comment: That would fly in this case @CodyGray because the feature set of [docker] of both [linux] and [windows] is the same? Because I'm not convinced I 100% agree with your convention in the general case.

Comment: Yeah, if the two things are actually different, I agree they should have dedicated tags. But the general case *is* that cross-platform tools are similar on each platform.

Comment: There's no such thing as docker for windows, or on windows. It's like saying firefox on windows, or c on linux. Yes, there may have been bugs specific to one implementation or another, but such things are programming related like bugs on random applications are.

Comment: The reason I came across these tags is that I'm looking at an issue that I currently believe to be specific to docker on windows. Although it's cross platform, most docker documentation is linux specific, so being able to identify/follow questions that aren't the "default" platform is very useful.

That said, I've had a quick look an equivalent [sql-server-on-linux] or similar tag, and it seems there the convention is separate tags for [sql-server] and [linux], as most have expressed a preference for above.

Comment: Any update on the merging?

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do the merge myself, if there's a consensus could someone else do the merge?

Comment: @Braiam are you sure about that? The tag wiki specifies a concept called "docker for windows" https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/, including specific installation manuals for "docker for windows" https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/, and there are answers that talk about its specifics https://stackoverflow.com/a/57332535. We _can_ go with Cody's approach of [docker][windows], _but_ if it really is a concept, then we should stick with [docker-for-windows] (I have rolled back the status tags for this, waiting for a reply from you before I add them back again).

Comment: @BhargavRao If you can demonstrate that exporting a docker file or container from one system to the other needs somehow changing the structure of the container/file to account for differences, that argument would be more valid. But [that's not the case](https://hovercraft.ie/switching-between-linux-and-windows-os-to-run-your-docker-container/). From the application developer perspective, docker behaves the same way in both Linux and Windows. In fact, that's the whole selling point of using Docker.

Comment: @Braiam Ok, thanks. I will write an answer detailing the steps as to how we can retag the questions in that tag to [docker][windows] instead. (perhaps tomorrow morning).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments underneath the question:

> There's no such thing as docker for windows, or on windows. It's like saying firefox on windows, or c on linux. Yes, there may have been bugs specific to one implementation or another, but such things are programming related like bugs on random applications are. - [Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355053/merge-tags-docker-for-windows-docker-on-windows-and-docker-windows#comment504244_355053)

and

> In my opinion, the convention should be [docker] [windows] (i.e., separate tags). - [Cody](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355053/merge-tags-docker-for-windows-docker-on-windows-and-docker-windows#comment504198_355053)

Converting both the tags into [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) and [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) seems to be a good idea. The plan for this would be:

1. We need to merge all these tags into one, which is [docker-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows) as that is the largest tag. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
2. We need to add [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) for all the questions that don't have the tag, but are tagged with [docker-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows), i.e, [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker-for-windows%5D+-%5Bdocker%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0). We need a CM to do this step for us. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
3. <s>We merge the tag with [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), in this way all the questions in the tag will have both [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tags.</s>   As Von [mentions in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355053/merge-tags-docker-for-windows-docker-on-windows-and-docker-windows/388455?noredirect=1#comment721487_388455), having [docker-for-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-for-windows) as a tag makes sense, so we end at Step 2.

That said, I would really like a top user in the [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tag to review if breaking the tag is necessary. If we do not need to break the tag, then we are already done with the merger of the 3 tags and we can call it a day.

Comment: Oh wow, VonC is the top user in [docker], I'm pretty sure that they'll help. I will ask them.

Comment: docker-for-windows makes sense (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) and is short for Docker Desktop on Windows, using Hyper-V (keep the docker tag as well though, as mentioned in your point 2)

Comment: [docker for mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) is also a separate product. Not entirely sure about Linux, but it doesn't appear to have a desktop variant, so that would make more sense to tag `[docker][linux]` or `[docker][unix-variant]` (unless I'm missing other products, but that's also not the primary discussion here).

Comment: Thanks for that, @VonC, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Looking good! Thank you for this important moderation work.